# Is there a way to use char16_t or char32_t in a linux kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, wchar-t

I was wondering if there is a way to use the types char16_t and char32_t (that were introduced in c11) inside a linux kernel module. I didn't find anything about that.

I just wanted to play with it, so I don't really need it.

Thanks,

p0kR

Comment: You definitely cannot define 16bit/32bit *string literals* with `u"abc"` or `U"abc"`: C89 doesn't support them. Also, in the Linux kernel there is no functions which support unicode. Without these features, types `char16_t` and `char32_t` have no advantage against `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`, which already exist in the kernel. BTW, if I understand correctly, `char16_t` and `char32_t` have appeared only in **c11**, not in c99.

Comment: OK, thanks. Of course I meant C11, I just typed it wrong.

Comment: The question is why do you need them?